# Graph theory : Travel to each Edge at least one and returning to the starting Node with the Shortest path in a Weighted Graph?

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

I would like to travel to each edge of the weighted graph at least once choosing the shortest path, i know this problem is similar to the Chinese Postman Problem CPP, but the difference here is that the Start Node is the same Ending Node, it's like an Eulerian circuit but we can travel to the same edge more than once if we need too.

I don't need the exact path but the Value of the Shortest Path

The number of nodes N can be  1 <= N <= 20
The number of Edges M can be  1 <= M <= 100
The weight of the Edges W can be 1 <= W <= 100

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: add a dummy vertex linked to your start node and end node with edges of weight zero, and you are reduced to the chinese postman problem